# Types in a package object

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but:

package.scala

```
package heptic

package object proj {
  case class Jesus(axes: Int)
  def foo: Jesus = Jesus(44)
}
```

Gives a compilation error:

```
found   : heptic.proj.Jesus
required: heptic.proj.package.Jesus
def foo: Jesus = Jesus(44)
                      ^
```

which doesn't seem to make an enormous amount of sense (especially when type inference crashes the compiler (latest, 2.10.1))

Comment: Is it the only file in your project? It seems there is another `Jesus` class.

Comment: there is no other Jesus class (but it's not the only file in the project)

Comment: `echo '<your code>' > package.scala` + `sbt compile` => `[success] Total time: 3 s`. Empty project, `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"`.

Comment: Updated, with a full project example

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/espringe/euler.git` + `cd euler/` + `sbt compile` => `[success] Total time: 38 s`. `[info] This is sbt 0.12.2`, `[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.1`, `[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2`

Comment: `grep -r "Jesus" .` - nothing found.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Very strange! I tried a new checkout, and it works fine. Did a git status, on the broken copy, and there's no outstanding changes. Did a `git clean -dfx` and it works fine. I guess we can chalk this up to stale temporary files?

Comment: For what its worth, here is the crash that scalac was giving when I tried to let it use type inference: https://gist.github.com/espringe/5541953

Comment: `sbt clean` for such errors. There was another class `Jesus` compiled and not deleted. I guess you have moved `Jesus` from package to package object and get both of them.

Comment: ^ If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt clean` for such errors.

There was another class `Jesus` compiled and not deleted. I guess you have moved `Jesus` from `package` to `package object` and get both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I order to make this work correctly, I believe that you need to place this code into a file called `package.scala` under the folder structure '/heptic/proj' (under your source folder).  The scala file needs to be called `package.scala` and it needs to be under the matching package folder structure for it to truly behave like a package object.

Comment: That half-works. Namely, now it compiles -- but the package object isn't acting like a package object (namely its not implicitly in scope for everything in package heptic.proj )

Comment: Updated with a different solution.  You should be able to leave code as is just tweak the file name it is contained in (and location if it's not in the right spot)

Comment: no, the scala compiler doesn't care at all about filenames nor directory structure

Answer (score 0):

declare the case class in the package but not in the package object:

```
package heptic

package object proj {
  def foo: Jesus = Jesus(44)
}

package proj {
  case class Jesus(axes: Int)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works fine. But kind of just side-steps the problem -- and I'd rather know what's going on :D